# When a liquid solidifies why does internal energy fall?

Tags: energy, solid-state-physics, potential-energy, kinetic-theory

Is it because the potential energy falls or is it because the kinetic energy falls .

Comment: What potential energy? Molecular kinetic energy typically decreases now that the free flowing molecules are stuck in an atomic structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, contrary to what Lemon said, internal energy is sum of ALL energy of constituting particles related to their DISORDERED motion only. To prove my statement, look out for the derivation of formula for internal energy for an IDEAL gas, and the derivation for value of C(molar heat capacity at constant volume) henceforth. 

Now coming to your question, since a solid is more compact than a liquid(obviously) kinetic energy is reduced to almost zero. What now comes into play is the potential energy. But the change in potential energy is far less than the change in Kinetic energy. Therefore, loss in "kinetic" internal energy is far greater than gain in "potential" internal energy.Thus overall loss of internal energy takes place.

P.S. Resulting energy(Kinetic or potential) of system due external force fields is excluded. Pay attention to the word DISORDERED above.